# Reading arduino serial connection in python: Unknown characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.x, arduino

I'm using Python to talk to my Arduino using the `pyserial` module.

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
```

I get the following results:

```
ser.read(20)
'y8\t0.16\t0.16\t-0.65\r\n'
```

That's what I need.

But if I close port and open it again, I get the following:

```
ser.close()
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
ser.read(20)
'4\xfa\x9a\xf9t\xff\x1a\xffA\xff<\xf2x\xf68\xf6A\xffA\xff'
```

What are these symbols? How do I get the correct characters?

My OS is Ubuntu

Comment: In Python 3.x the strings are unicode by default. When sending data to Arduino, they have to be converted to bytes. Do you used prefixes for the values (e.g. >>> ser.write(b'5')), such as it is explained here: http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/python ?

Answer (score 0):

These are unicode characters that are "backslash replaced". Basically, [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which is a list of characters (like `A` or `%`), cannot represent all of the characters in [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) (a longer list of characters than ASCII). I would suggest that you look at [the codecs library to deal with unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#module-codecs).